# how to auto close empty elements in XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am working with an XML (I am average in XML) document, in which I want to auto close all the empty elements, eg:

**From** :

```
<colgroup>
    <col class="Row-Column-1">
    <col class="Row-Column-2">
    <col class="Row-Column-3">
    <col class="Row-Column-4">
</colgroup>
```

**To** :

```
<colgroup>
    <col class="Row-Column-1"/>
    <col class="Row-Column-2"/>
    <col class="Row-Column-3"/>
    <col class="Row-Column-4"/>
</colgroup>
```

Can anybody suggest an idea to do this using any way or any command line tools like "**tidy**".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way to deal with invalid XML is to fix the program (or person) that created it. The benefit of XML as a standard for data interchange depends on people following the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Your "from" portion that will be your source XML isn't a valid XML. So what you are trying is convert an invalid xml to a valid one.

Since XSLT is mainly meant for transforming a valid xml to to something else like (XML,HTML,Text), currently what you are trying ins't possible via XSLT.

What you can do is read the data in string format in some programming language and do the change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Saurav, I am looking to solve this using perl, but i didnt finished it, so meanwhile I was searching for any command line tool to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your question tags (xml xslt xslt-1.0 xslt-2.0) are wrong, you should tag your question with Perl - your chosen language for the fix - as currently you are only asking for XML/XSLT answers, while your source file isn't even XML.

Whatever language you choose, a search-and-replace of "> to "/> would do the trick. If the sequence "> occurs elsewhere in the document, you will need to do a regular expression search-and-replace instead. Something like

Search term:

```
(<col class="Row-Column-[0-9]+)(">)
```

Replacement term:

```
\$1"/>
```

At least, that is what I would do in IntelliJ, which support regexp search-and-replace.

Comment: God no, using XSLT to string process malformed XML to try and make it Well-formed? That's a war crime in some states.

Comment: Er, I'm saying DON'T do that!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I suggest reading first, shooting later. I am upvoting this answer to offset the downvote.